# Python Flask App not running Thread on Azure

Tags: python, azure, flask, python-multithreading

My code is working fine on localhost but the thread is not working when deployed on Azure.
Code looks something like this:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from side import querying, send_message
import json
from threading import Thread

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/chat', methods=['POST'])
def chat():
    body = json.loads(request.data.decode())['body']
    category = json.loads(request.data.decode())['category']
    phone = json.loads(request.data.decode())['phone']

    def do_work(body, category, phone):
        answer = querying(body, category)
        send_message(phone, answer)

    thread = Thread(target=do_work, kwargs={'body': body, "category":category, "phone":phone})
    thread.start()
    return 'started'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=False, port=5000)
```

I'm expecting it to work on Azure as good as it is working on localhost

Answer (score 0):

I made a little changes to your code and tried to execute in my environment. I was able to deploy to Azure successfully.

```py
from  flask  import  Flask, request
from  side.querying  import  querying
from  side.send_message  import  send_message
import  json
from  threading  import  Thread
app  =  Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/chat', methods=['POST'])
def  chat():
body  =  json.loads(request.data.decode())['body']
category  =  json.loads(request.data.decode())['category']
phone  =  json.loads(request.data.decode())['phone']
def  do_work(body, category, phone):
answer  =  querying(body, category)
send_message(phone, answer)
thread  =  Thread(target=do_work, kwargs={'body': body, "category":category, "phone":phone})
thread.start()
return  "started"
if  __name__  ==  '__main__':
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=False, port=5000)
```

Executed successfully in local environment:

[image]

Deployed successfully as shown:

[image]

[image]

After deployment, go to  `Advanced tools`  under  `Development tools`  of an App service, you can be able to view the deployments as shown.

[image]

Update :
I can be able to view the send_message in logstream of an appservice post deployment.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Bhavani and AsleshaKantamsetti, thanks for your reply!
This code works something like this, first the flask app responds "started" and in the background querying and send_message starts working, which takes around 10s and then hit whatsapp api and send message to user.
Currently in my azure deployment, I'm able to receive "started" but the send_message is not running in the background. Please suggest if your code is running send_message after responding "started"? Shall I make changes in the code or there is some changes required in azure deployment settings?

Comment: @akshaysoni I updated the answer. Can you please check if it is working.